# How to insert value in Publishing LinkField using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-fields

I want to save data into list but it gives me error when used following code.

```
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.ListNameListItem" },
    "Hyperlink": { Url: $('[id$=txtLinksURL]').val(), Description: $('[id$=txtLinksDescription]').val()}
};

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US"
,"value":"The property 'Hyperlink' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.ArticleHyperlinksListItem'. Make
 sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}
```

How to set Hyperlink Value Using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setPublisingHyperlinkValue(fieldInternalName,url,description)
{
    var fieldUrl = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName +  '][id $=UrlFieldUrl]');
    var fieldDesc = $('input[id ^=' + fieldInternalName + '][id $=UrlFieldDescription]');
    fieldUrl.val(url);
    fieldDesc.val(description);
}
```